# using tryCatch/showNotification for RShiny while using functions with internal stop() command

Tags: r, shiny, try-catch

Suppose I have a Rshiny app that takes numericInput via `mynum`, keeps the entry in a list after pressing go button, undergoes function `CheckOdd`, form a table `resultTable` for that number, while keeping the result on a separate table `resultHistory`.

The function `CheckOdd` has internal `stop()` command that returns error message, but if ran inside Shiny environment, it will crash the app.

I want to prevent crashing and display that specific error message instead. While there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587883/is-it-possible-to-stop-executing-of-r-code-inside-shiny-without-stopping-the-sh) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216300/trying-to-catch-an-errror-while-using-r-shiny) [questions](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2894), I could not find one for Rshiny that

- defines function at global level, rather than defined in server
- has stop() command inside that function

How can I write tryCatch/showNotification that it will effectively catch the error without crashing the app, without the separate use of `verbatimText`?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

CheckOdd <- function(num){
  if(is.na(num)){stop("num is NA")}
  if((num %% 2) == 0){stop("num is even")}
  result <- c(num, num+1, num+3, num+5)
  return(result)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,
         numericInput("mynum","Enter Number", value = 4),
         actionButton("go_button", "Assess"),
         hr(),
         tableOutput("resultTable")
  ),
  column(6,
         DT::dataTableOutput("resultHistory")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myentry <- eventReactive(input$go_button, {
    list(
      mynum = input$mynum
    )
  })

  myvector <- reactive({
    CheckOdd(myentry()$mynum)
  })


  output$resultTable <- renderTable({
    tbl1 <- data.frame(
      "zero" = myvector()[1],
      "one" = myvector()[2],
      "three" = myvector()[3],
      "five" = myvector()[4]
    )
    tbl1
  })

  history <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      "num" = integer(),
      "plus_one" = integer(),
      "plus_three" = integer(),
      "plus_five" = integer()
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$go_button, {
    t <- rbind(history(),
               data.frame(
                 "zero" = myvector()[1],
                 "one" = myvector()[2],
                 "three" = myvector()[3],
                 "five" = myvector()[4]
               )
    )
    history(t)
  })

  output$resultHistory <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    history()
  }))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The notion of a global exception handler that catches some deeply-nested `stop()` is problematic to begin with, as it can be mis-used, abused, etc, though it exists as [`globalCallingHandlers`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html); be careful with it. Having said that, this means that you want to define in the global environment something that will know how to reach inside the reactive nature of a running shiny app and display a modal popup or message to the user ... I suggest it is _far simpler_ to catch errors on known-problematic calls like that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest staying specific with individual calls of `tryCatch`.

I've done a few things here:

- added `req(.)` in a couple of places, it helps enforce reactive dependency requirements so that when something upstream breaks, its "error-state" is back-channeled to dependencies in a smart way;
- this back-channel error-state is created here using `validate(need(cond, text))`; normally the `cond` would be `inherits(res, "error")`, but unfortunately the `conditionMessage(res)` is *always* called, and this fails when `res` is not an error ... so we take a little care to only call `validate(need(...))` when we know it'll be a problem

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myentry <- eventReactive(input$go_button, {
    list(
      mynum = input$mynum
    )
  })

  myvector <- reactive({
    mye <- req(myentry())
    res <- tryCatch(
      CheckOdd(mye$mynum),
      error = function(e) e)
    if (inherits(res, "error")) {
      validate(
        need(FALSE, paste("ERROR:", conditionMessage(res)))
      )
    }
    res
  })


  output$resultTable <- renderTable({
    vec <- req(myvector())
    tbl1 <- data.frame(
      "zero" = vec[1],
      "one" = vec[2],
      "three" = vec[3],
      "five" = vec[4]
    )
    tbl1
  })

  history <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      "num" = integer(),
      "plus_one" = integer(),
      "plus_three" = integer(),
      "plus_five" = integer()
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$go_button, {
    vec <- req(myvector())
    t <- rbind(history(),
               data.frame(
                 "zero" = vec[1],
                 "one" = vec[2],
                 "three" = vec[3],
                 "five" = vec[4]
               )
    )
    history(t)
  })

  output$resultHistory <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    history()
  }))
}
```

When this works, the `resultTable` shows the one row just fine; when there's an error, it presents `ERROR: error message ...`.

[image: shiny with validation error message]